# Returning the range for an unknown int type

Tags: c

I have been assigned a question where someone could put in potentially any type of signed/unsigned integer and two functions have to return the respective min and max using bitwise operations, etc.

I am trying to adjust what I know about two's complement — the range is defined by -(2<sup>n-1</sup>) to (2<sup>n-1</sup> - 1) for signed, and 0 to (2<sup>n</sup> - 1) for unsigned values.

However, when I use the following approach for unsigned:

```
void create_minmax_unsigned() {
    unknownun exponent = (sizeof(unknownun) * 8) - 1;
    unknownun max = (1 << exponent) - 1;
    printf("The max is %d", max);
}
```

And for signed:

```
void create_minmax_signed() {
    unknowns exponent = (sizeof(unknowns) * 8) - 1;
    unknowns min = ((1 << exponent) + 1) - 1;
    unknowns max = (1 << exponent) - 1;
}
```

This approach will work for char (un/s), short (un/s), int (un/s), long (un/s) but not long long, which is 64 bits.

EDIT: It is actually returning the correct number of bits for all of the int types. However, for `long long`, it is not displaying the correct range.

Comment: Which compiler and platform are you using? (1) If `sizeof(long long) == 4`, then `CHAR_BITS == 16` or some larger value, if the compiler is standard compliant.  The `long long` type must be at least 64 bits in a conforming compiler. (2) It really isn't clear what you're trying to do.  A single C function can really only take a single type for its argument, unless you get into variadic functions with pointers to different types (or, perhaps, with `void *` to the different types).  But you need to know what type was passed somehow.  And I still can't guess what use anyone is going to make of it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It could be a macro...

Comment: OK; a macro isn't a function, though.  Do you want a macro or a function?  What is the use case for this construct?  What are you seeking to achieve.  This feels like an [XY Question](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem); you're asking for the solution to X but you're really seeking to solve Y.

Comment: Function, and it's not really meant to be useful. It's just an exercise.

Comment: You can't do that in a function, because a function gets its arguments passed as a known type: `[return_type] function([argument_type argument])`. You already **know** what type the arguments are.

Comment: Can you show how these functions will be called, and what the return values will be?  Is the 'max' function supposed to return the upper bound of the smallest type that can hold the passed value?  How will you know whether the value is passed in as signed or unsigned?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. (How can you tell if a number is signed or unsigned?) Anyway, the notation `~0` will give you an integer with all bits set.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage How would you use that in a expression to get the max?

Comment: For an unsigned int, `max = ~0;`. For a signed int, you could perhaps cast the result to an unsigned int and divide by 2 (then add one to get the minimum value after casting back to a signed int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the `long long` computation fails is that the RHS of the assignments is calculated as `int` and you are trying to shift by values that are too large for `int`.

This spiel develops the answer step-wise — only the final code is really workable.  Earlier versions have various issues that have to be resolved, one issue at a time.

You need to coerce the RHS into the specified type:

```
void create_minmax_unsigned() {
    unknownun exponent = (sizeof(unknownun) * 8) - 1;
    unknownun max = ((unknownun)1 << exponent) - 1;
    printf("The max is %d", max);
}

void create_minmax_signed() {
    unknowns exponent = (sizeof(unknowns) * 8) - 1;
    unknowns min = (((unknowns)1 << exponent) + 1) - 1;
    unknowns max = ((unknowns)1 << exponent) - 1;
}
```

You have a problem with returning multiple values.  Your printing code could be made more robust with `<inttypes.h>` and `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t` casts:

```
void create_minmax_unsigned() {
    unknownun exponent = (sizeof(unknownun) * 8) - 1;
    unknownun max = ((unknownun)1 << exponent) - 1;
    printf("The max is %" PRIuMAX, (uintmax_t)max);
}

void create_minmax_signed() {
    unknowns exponent = (sizeof(unknowns) * 8) - 1;
    unknowns min = (((unknowns)1 << exponent) + 1) - 1;
    unknowns max = ((unknowns)1 << exponent) - 1;
    printf("The max is %" PRIdMAX, (intmax_t)max);
    printf("The min is %" PRIdMAX, (intmax_t)min);
}
```

#### Resolving overflow problems

So far, this leaves your calculation substantially unchanged; it just ensures that the values are of the correct type.  However, your calculation is vulnerable to numeric overflow, which is (potentially) very bad — it leads to undefined behaviour with signed integer types and wrong answers for unsigned types.

For an unsigned type where you can't use a larger type to cover your sins, you need to create 2<sup>n</sup>-1 carefully, because `2<sup>n</sup>` is bigger than can be stored, so it looks like 0. When you subtract 1, you get the correct answer, but you really didn't need the shifting/exponentiation.

```
void create_minmax_unsigned() {
    unknownun max = (unknownun)0 - 1;
    printf("The max is %" PRIuMAX, (uintmax_t)max);
}
```

For the signed types, you can't use 2<sup>n-1</sup> - 1 because 2<sup>n-1</sup> cannot be represented.  You can use 2 * (2<sup>n-2</sup> - 1) + 1, though.  The negative limit is that value negated with one subtracted, leading to:

---

Untested code (buggy):

```
void create_minmax_signed() {
    unknowns exponent = (sizeof(unknowns) * 8) - 2;
    unknowns max = 2 * ((unknowns)1 << exponent) + 1;
    unknowns min = -max - 1;
    printf("The max is %" PRIdMAX, (intmax_t)max);
    printf("The min is %" PRIdMAX, (intmax_t)min);
}
```

Tested code (not so buggy):

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef signed long long unknowns;
void create_minmax_signed(void);

void create_minmax_signed(void)
{
    unknowns exponent = (sizeof(unknowns) * 8) - 2;
    unknowns max = 2 * (((unknowns)1 << exponent) - 1) + 1;
    unknowns min = -max - 1;
    printf("The max is %+" PRIdMAX "\n", (intmax_t)max);
    printf("The min is %+" PRIdMAX "\n", (intmax_t)min);
}

int main(void)
{
  create_minmax_signed();
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -g -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration -Werror  mnx.c -o mnx
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./mnx
The max is +9223372036854775807
The min is -9223372036854775808
$
```

Comment: Isn't -max - 1 the min, not the max?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten a `-1` in `create_minmax_signed()` (`max = 2 * ((1<<exp)-1) +1`) . Also, it seems to assume two's-complement representation for signed ints, which is not specified by the standard.

Comment: @EOF: The question assumes two's complement; the answer does too.  And yes, you're right; I forgot a -1 in the expression.  Answer updated with tested code (and the test code).  There's a reason I prefer to post tested code...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was referring to the version of `void create_minmax_signed()` at the start of the post (The first two versions, actually). If the version at the end is supposed to replace it, then it should actually replace it...

Comment: The stuff at the beginning has problems; the rest of the post spends time identifying and fixing them.  The first version is most certainly not the final working version -- to the extent that the last is a working version.  The final version isn't much use as it doesn't return the value(s); it just prints them.  However, it does calculate them accurately and safely (I think).

Comment: I see now, the first two versions are meant to be "still broken but not quite as bad" . OK, ignore me..:)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I've put an explicit 'stepwise development' and 'issues to be resolved' disclaimer at the top in an attempt to prevent your confusion reoccurring.

Comment: A very clear answer! An alternative (and imho insanely elegant) implementation is https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-compat-util.h (see "maximum_unsigned_value_of_type(x)" and its signed sibling)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just shift `1 << (sizeof(signed type)*CHAR_BIT-1)`, because that's undefined behaviour (if `sizeof(signed type) >= sizeof(int)`). Also, what is `(x+1)-1`? (Hint: `x`, unless `x` was INT_MAX, in which case it's undefined). So that doesn't get you a negative number, does it?

Comment: Sorry - really new to this - and not following. Are you asking what the last line of the program is doing or suggesting something through the expression (x + 1) - 1?